# Need to know what is Mid([GTIN],2,10) in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access

I've been given a query to use in some PHP code but the problem is, the person that gave me the query is using MS Access and I'm using MySQL so everything isn't quite translating.  In his query there is this 
`... Mid([GTIN],2,10) AS items_bar ...` 
MySQL doesn't like this part and I'm not sure what it is supposed to be doing.  Is there an easy translation for this to MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is selecting a sub-string of the GTIN element.

Instead of using this:

```
Mid([GTIN],2,10) AS items_bar
```

Use this:

```
substring(GTIN,2,10) as items_bar
```